# Botany inquiry about tropism

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, botany

Can anyone explain the mechanism of hydrotropism and what kind of plant hormone involved?
Our teacher says that it hasn't been proven yet. I looked up many data only to find about the phenomenon of this effect.